# Excel VBA to Copy Values to Filtered Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel (365?) workbook with 3 worksheets:  1). Data Entry, 2). Data Review, and 3). Data Table.  I have created a long VBA code in Sheet 1 to copy entered data into a table on Sheet3.  I have a INDEX MATCH function working in the cells on Sheet2 for Data Review to pull information from the table based on selection of a name from the data table.  However, I am stuck on how to copy a users input from cell F93 on Sheet2, into the filtered Data Table's (Sheet3) cell CD2 that corresponds to the filtered data name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this code, but it adds new lines every time, and doesn't add the QRNotes to the filtered name's information.  Instead, I need the value to be entered into
cell CD2 or at least the row that the rest of the filtered data is in (Row#2).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim QRNotes As Worksheet, DataLog As Worksheet

Set QRNotes = Sheet2
Set DataLog = CaseHistory

Dim QRCaseNotes As Range

Set QRCaseNotes = CTrk.Range("F86")

Dim DestCell As Range
If CLog.Range("A2") = "" Then
    Set DestCell = CLog.Range("A2")
Else
    Set DestCell = CLog.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End If


QRCaseNotes.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 82)


ClaimID.ClearContents


End Sub
```

Comment: Some screenshots would be useful here.